# Use hashes in Perl HTML::Template::Compiled

Tags: perl, hash, cgi

Can't show hash keys and values.

The code is like from the examples at http://search.cpan.org/~tinita/HTML-Template-Compiled-1.003/lib/HTML/Template/Compiled.pm

```
use HTML::Template::Compiled;

my $template = HTML::Template::Compiled->new(filename => '/usr/share/nginx/status.tmpl');

$template->param(
    letters => {
        1 => { letter =>'b' },
        2 => { letter =>'a' },
        3 => { letter =>'c' },
    }, 
);

print($template->output);
```

Template:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Template</title></head>
<body>
    <%each letters%>
        <%set_var val value=__value__ %>
        <%= __key__ %>=<%= $val.letter %>
    <%/each%>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is '= = ='. So the `__key__` and `__value__` aren't printed at all. That happens even without nested hashes, but this example code is the simplest of the ones on the documentation page.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the `loop_context_vars` option.

```
my $template = HTML::Template::Compiled->new(loop_context_vars => 1, filename => '/usr/share/nginx/status.tmpl');
```